# Import or parse a txt file into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, text-files, tidyverse

I'm trying to import a text file into a dataframe.  Records in the text file are separated by 56 dashes.  The file looks like this:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------
    Record: 1
    ColumnTitleABC: string of text
    ColumnTitleDEFG: string of text
    --------------------------------------------------------
    Record: 2
    ColumnTitleABC: string of text
    ColumnTitleDEFG: string of text
    --------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried using `read_delim("TextFileName.txt", delim = ":")`.
It just returns the column titles without the strings of text.  Is there a better R function to read in this type of text file?  Or maybe there would be some way to parse this in R before moving it into a dataframe?

I would like the end result to be a dataframe like this:

```
    Record  ColumnTitleABC  ColumnTitleDEFG
    1       string of text  string of text
    2       string of text  string of text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do some preprocessing with the data before getting it into a useable format.

```
lines <- readLines('data.txt')

do.call(rbind, by(lines, cumsum(grepl('------', lines)), function(x) {
  x <- x[-1]
  name <- sub(':.*', '', x)
  value <- sub('.*:', '', x)
  setNames(as.data.frame(t(value)), name)
})) -> result

result
#    Record  ColumnTitleABC ColumnTitleDEFG
#1        1  string of text  string of text
#2        2  string of text  string of text
```

- `cumsum(grepl('------', lines))` would create groups which will separate one record from another.
- `x <- x[-1]` is done since the 1st value in each group is just `------` line, so we remove it.
- `name <- sub(':.*', '', x)` removes everything after colon to get the column name.
- `value <- sub('.*:', '', x)` removes everything before colon to the get the value.
- `setNames(as.data.frame(t(value)), name)` creates a 1 X 3 dataframe.

Comment: Ronak, this worked very well in creating a dataframe from way the data was formatted in the text file.  Thank you also for the explanations with the code.